# Validity of switching on template parameter to improve type safety

Tags: c++, templates, types, enums, compiler-warnings

I have a function which takes an enum value and other assorted values as parameters. Depending on the value of the enum, the function manipulates the other parameters in different ways. I know for a fact that the function cannot be called with one or more of the potential enum values. For example:

```
enum class Colour { RED, GREEN, BLUE, BLACK};

// Pre: colour != Colour::BLACK
void do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour(Colour colour, /*other args*/) {
    assert(colour != Colour::BLACK);
    switch (colour) {
        case Colour::RED:   // do thing A
        case Colour::GREEN: // do thing B
        case Colour::BLUE:  // do thing C
    }
}
```

On compilation, I get a compiler warning because I didn't explicitly handle the `colour == Colour::BLACK` case. To appease the compiler, I have to include something like `default:  // this never happens`.

A coworker suggested templating on `Colour`, because it allows the compiler to statically ascertain that the function template is never called with the invalid enum value:

```
template<Colour colour>
void do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour(/*other args*/) {
    switch (colour) {
        case Colour::RED:   // do thing A
        case Colour::GREEN: // do thing B
        case Colour::BLUE:  // do thing C
    }
}
```

At compile-time, the compiler will give a warning on instantiation of `do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour<Colour::BLACK>(...)` because that case is not handled in the switch-case. We can enforce this more strictly with `static_assert`. However to me this seems like an abuse of template parameters because logically the enum is a parameter to the function, and furthermore the switch case becomes essentially useless because each of the enum values is now handled by a separate function entirely. So in each function, only one of the cases ever triggers.

Is this a recommended (or at least valid) use of template parameters?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to mix a runtime switch with a compile time mechanism. How would you use this thing in practice?

Comment: You would replace `do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour(Colour::RED, ...)` with  `do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour<Colour::RED>(...)` and so on for the other enum values.

Comment: Yes, but how would you decide which function template instantiation to call?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question... you call whichever one is appropriate for whatever you're trying to do. If you were colouring a shape blue, you would call `colour_shape<Colour::BLUE>(shape)`.

Answer (score 0):

As you observed, if you make `Colour` a template parameter of the
function `do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour` rather than a
runtime function parameter, whenever you write a call to
`do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour` it can only do the thing
that you decided prior to compiling the code.
If executing a function call from line N of file F sometimes 
colors an object red, then executing that function call *always* colors an object red.

If you call `do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour` from within
a function with a signature like
`void do_more_complex_thing(Colour colour)`,
you will need a separate call to `do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour`
to handle each color that might be passed to `do_more_complex_thing`.
Or you could write specialized templates for
`do_more_complex_thing`, but you could very quickly be looking
at massive amounts of duplicated code if you go far down this path,
making maintenance of this code base nightmarish.

But if you can live with the constraint that the `Colour` parameter
of `do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour` must always be known at compile time,
you can eliminate the switch statement by using template specialization:

```
template <Colour> void do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour();

template <> void do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour<Colour::RED>() {
  // do thing A
}
template <> void do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour<Colour::GREEN>() {
  // do thing B
}
template <> void do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour<Colour::BLUE>() {
  // do thing C
}
```

In addition to eliminating the need for `switch`, this design ensures
that a call to `void do_thing_assuming_nonblack_colour<Colour::BLACK>()`
will not just cause a compiler warning;
it will cause a compile-time *error,*
giving you even better protection against accidentally
calling this function with the parameter `Colour::BLACK`.